# CSS Menu Disappears in Safari and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, safari, z-index

Having a lot of difficult with my CSS hover menu in Safari and Internet Explorer 11. I think it may have to do with the z-index, but please take a look at my JSFiddle for code reference. So confused! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The live site can be viewed at rebeckacalderwood.com

http://jsfiddle.net/mfraser801/c3E9m/

The CSS: 
    #menu {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    }

```
#menu ul {
text-align: center;
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
color: #87602F;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: -4px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
padding: 15px 50px;
background: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s;
-o-transition: all 0.2s;
transition: all 0.2s;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
background: #5B1626;
color: #fff;
z-index: 1;
}

#menu ul li ul {
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
top: 48px;
left: 0;
width: 185px;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
display: none;
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
-transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

#menu ul li ul li { 
background: #5B1626; 
display: block; 
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}

#menu ul li ul li:hover { 
z-index: 100;
background: #87602F; 
}

#menu ul li:hover ul {
z-index: 100;
color: #fff;
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<nav>
<ul>
<a href="profile.html"><li>PROFILE</li></a>
<a href="resume.html"><li>RESUME</li></a>
<li>
<a href style="color: #87602F;"="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
<ul>
<a href="album_reviews.html"><li>WORDS</li></a>  
<a href="photos - events.html"><li>PHOTOS</li></a>
<a href="audio.html"><li>AUDIO</li></a>
<a href="video.html"><li>VIDEO</li></a>  </ul>
</li>              
<a href="contact.html"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your website and the code in jsfiddle is different. This is the HTML from your website:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href="profile.html"><li>PROFILE</li></a>
        <a href="resume.html"><li>RESUME</li></a>
        <a href="album_reviews.html"> <li>PORTFOLIO</li></a>
        <a href="contact.html"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Compare that to the jsfiddle example that your provided. You are missing the nested `ul`. And while you have the `#menu ul li:hover ul`, your code structure there is different and there is nothing to apply that style to.

By the way, the jsfiddle works just fine in IE11.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. CLick on "portfolio" and then you can see the nested menu. The jsfiddle might work fine, but it doesn't work fine on the actualy website.

Comment: Try removing z-index from a.imgLink and .video. I managed to get it working in Safari that way. #slider a.imgLink, #slider .video { remove z-index from here }. Or set it to 0 or a negative value.